# Extracting text while keeping the structure

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0, xpath-1.0

Assume I have the following document:

```
<bookstore>
<book>
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <price>29.99</price>
  Berlin
</book>
<book>
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <price>39.95</price>
  Tokyo
</book>
</bookstore>
```

How can I get the following document using *XPath*?

```
<bookstore>
<book>
  Berlin
</book>
<book>
  Tokyo
</book>
</bookstore>
```

I tried `/bookstore/book/text()` but that obviously destroys the structure of the document.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that uses XSLT or XQuery (both based on XPath)?  As already mentioned, this is not a use case for just XPath.

Comment: A solution with XSLT or XQuery would be perfect. I did not realize that these transformations are not possible with XPath when I posted the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible with XPath.
With XPath you can select single node, not return complex document structure.